# ISV Partner Docusign API Authentication Consent

Tags: docusignapi

We are working on an integration to offer embedded document signing through customer websites we host.  We want this to be a comprehensive solution, so envelopes should count against our quota, but will need to be under the user account provisioned through Docusign. We are using the JWT authentication method to impersonate the provisioned accounts and want to make sure we understand any requirements to gain consent.

When we request and provision accounts for our customers, is our integration key automatically granted consent on that account?  Will we need to set up a service user account that can be impersonated on each customer account and grant consent individually?  Thank you for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time we don't have these capabilities for ISVs.
Consent has to be given in the organization/account level (admin consent).
Which means if your customers are not in your organization, each of them would have to consent once.

Using administrator consent, your customers would only have to go through this process 1 time for your application.

Please free to send a feature request to [partners@docusign.com](http://mailto:partners@docusign.com) or contact your partner account manager ([make sure you're a DocuSign Partner](https://www.docusign.com/partners/become-partner)).

Comment: Thank you!  That really helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you (as an ISV) intend to purchase and provide the envelopes on behalf of your clients, you will need to be under an ISV License agreement with DocuSign.  Architecturally, you would not be adding your clients are users in the accounts owned and managed by you.  You would instead use a "system user" to represent each client organization.  This works especially well for embedded signing integrations.  As for consent, it would be a one-time consent that your configuration team would accomplish when onboarding the new client.

Comment: We are under the ISV License Agreement.  Would it need to be a single system user that  can be granted access to each client account?  Or would we need a system user created under each client account?

Comment: Taking this a step further, upon onboarding a new client, you submit an Account Provisioning request to DocuSign.  The "user" that you provide as initial admin user in that account should be one of your admins.  Your admin can then update account settings and add a system user to represent the business client.  You (the ISV vendor) control that system user and define the credentials.  You should have a setup/configuration process that allows the admin to consent as the system user.  From that point on, your integration can use your IK plus that system user's userId to get tokens.

Comment: They should be different system users.  Rationale:  1) reinforces access control - less likely to accidentally cross-access accounts.  System User A cannot be accidentally used to access Account B.  2) allows you to "personalize" the system sender to the client business, i.e. if client is Acme, acme@{ISV}.com.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much!